# Parse Unique and Sorted Properties JSON/Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

The following code pulls parses a list of values from JSON in alphanumeric order based on a key value pair:

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {



  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myObjjj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

    var result = myObjjj.features.filter(c => c.properties.AREAID === "area4").map(res => res.properties.CDNAME + "<br>").sort().join('');
    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = result;
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://api.npoint.io/eed1932ca3c208946d86", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Read data from External JSON file using JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>
        Data extracted from External JSON file using JavaScript.
    </h3>
    
        <p id="list" style="border: 2px solid yellow;"></p>
    

</body>
</html>
```

JSON from the URL

```
    {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4811","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 11","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4807","COLOR":"#00fffc","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area1","CDNAME":"Division No. 7","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4815","COLOR":"#fffc00","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area2","CDNAME":"Division No. 15","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4802","COLOR":"#ff0000","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area3","CDNAME":"Division No. 2","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4808","COLOR":"#00fffc","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area1","CDNAME":"Division No. 8","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4803","COLOR":"#fffc00","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area2","CDNAME":"Division No. 3","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4801","COLOR":"#ff0000","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area3","CDNAME":"Division No. 1","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4804","COLOR":"#ff0000","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area3","CDNAME":"Division No. 4","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4801","COLOR":"#ff0000","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area3","CDNAME":"Division No. 1","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4804","COLOR":"#ff0000","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area3","CDNAME":"Division No. 4","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4806","COLOR":"#fffc00","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area2","CDNAME":"Division No. 6","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4816","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 16","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4812","COLOR":"#0600ff","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area5","CDNAME":"Division No. 12","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4805","COLOR":"#fffc00","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area2","CDNAME":"Division No. 5","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4817","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 17","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4813","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 13","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4810","COLOR":"#0600ff","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area5","CDNAME":"Division No. 10","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4819","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 19","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4818","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 18","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4814","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 14","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4809","COLOR":"#00fffc","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area1","CDNAME":"Division No. 9","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4811","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 11","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4807","COLOR":"#00fffc","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area1","CDNAME":"Division No. 7","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4815","COLOR":"#fffc00","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area2","CDNAME":"Division No. 15","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4802","COLOR":"#ff0000","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area3","CDNAME":"Division No. 2","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4808","COLOR":"#00fffc","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area1","CDNAME":"Division No. 8","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4803","COLOR":"#fffc00","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area2","CDNAME":"Division No. 3","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4801","COLOR":"#ff0000","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area3","CDNAME":"Division No. 1","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4804","COLOR":"#ff0000","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area3","CDNAME":"Division No. 4","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4801","COLOR":"#ff0000","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area3","CDNAME":"Division No. 1","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4804","COLOR":"#ff0000","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area3","CDNAME":"Division No. 4","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4806","COLOR":"#fffc00","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area2","CDNAME":"Division No. 6","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4816","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 16","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4812","COLOR":"#0600ff","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area5","CDNAME":"Division No. 12","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4805","COLOR":"#fffc00","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area2","CDNAME":"Division No. 5","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4817","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 17","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4813","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 13","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4810","COLOR":"#0600ff","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area5","CDNAME":"Division No. 10","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4819","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 19","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4818","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 18","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4814","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 14","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4809","COLOR":"#00fffc","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area1","CDNAME":"Division No. 9","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4811","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 11","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4807","COLOR":"#00fffc","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area1","CDNAME":"Division No. 7","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4815","COLOR":"#fffc00","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area2","CDNAME":"Division No. 15","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4802","COLOR":"#ff0000","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area3","CDNAME":"Division No. 2","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4808","COLOR":"#00fffc","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area1","CDNAME":"Division No. 8","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4803","COLOR":"#fffc00","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area2","CDNAME":"Division No. 3","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4801","COLOR":"#ff0000","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area3","CDNAME":"Division No. 1","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4804","COLOR":"#ff0000","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area3","CDNAME":"Division No. 4","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4801","COLOR":"#ff0000","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area3","CDNAME":"Division No. 1","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4804","COLOR":"#ff0000","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area3","CDNAME":"Division No. 4","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4806","COLOR":"#fffc00","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area2","CDNAME":"Division No. 6","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4816","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 16","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4812","COLOR":"#0600ff","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area5","CDNAME":"Division No. 12","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4805","COLOR":"#fffc00","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area2","CDNAME":"Division No. 5","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4817","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 17","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4813","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 13","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4810","COLOR":"#0600ff","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area5","CDNAME":"Division No. 10","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4819","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 19","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4818","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 18","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4814","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 14","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4809","COLOR":"#00fffc","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area1","CDNAME":"Division No. 9","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4811","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 11","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4807","COLOR":"#00fffc","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area1","CDNAME":"Division No. 7","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4815","COLOR":"#fffc00","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area2","CDNAME":"Division No. 15","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4802","COLOR":"#ff0000","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area3","CDNAME":"Division No. 2","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4808","COLOR":"#00fffc","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area1","CDNAME":"Division No. 8","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4803","COLOR":"#fffc00","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area2","CDNAME":"Division No. 3","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4801","COLOR":"#ff0000","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area3","CDNAME":"Division No. 1","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4804","COLOR":"#ff0000","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area3","CDNAME":"Division No. 4","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4801","COLOR":"#ff0000","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area3","CDNAME":"Division No. 1","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4804","COLOR":"#ff0000","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area3","CDNAME":"Division No. 4","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4806","COLOR":"#fffc00","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area2","CDNAME":"Division No. 6","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4816","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 16","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4812","COLOR":"#0600ff","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area5","CDNAME":"Division No. 12","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4805","COLOR":"#fffc00","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area2","CDNAME":"Division No. 5","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4817","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 17","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4813","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Area No. 13","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4810","COLOR":"#0600ff","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area5","CDNAME":"Division No. 10","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4819","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 19","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4818","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Division No. 18","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4814","COLOR":"#ff00f0","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area4","CDNAME":"Center No. 14","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{"CDUID":"4809","COLOR":"#00fffc","PRUID":"48","AREAID":"area1","CDNAME":"Division No. 9","CDTYPE":"CDR","PRNAME":"Alberta","KML_STYLE":"area6"}}]}
```

I want the code to remove duplicate values so that the final result would look like this:

Area No. 13

Center No. 14

Division No. 11

Division No. 13

Division No. 14

Division No. 16

Division No. 17

Division No. 18

Division No. 19

Comment: What type of output are you looking for? A newline-delimited string? An array of strings or another JSON structure? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I want the same format as as in the yellow div, just no duplicates, I tried Array.from(new Set(result)); but that removed all duplicate characters, not what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code:

```js
var result = myObjjj.features.filter(c => c.properties.AREAID === "area4").map(res => res.properties.CDNAME + "<br>").sort().join('');
```

You'd need to handle the duplicates before the [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join). Also, there's no reason to use `.map()` to add `<br>` as `.join()` can do that.

Below, we use [`new Set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/Set) and [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to take care of the duplicates:

```js
const cdNames = myObjjj.features.filter(
  c => c.properties.AREAID === "area4"
).map(
  res => res.properties.CDNAME
);
const results = Array.from(new Set(cdNames)).sort().join('<br>');
```

1. Filter by `AREAID`
2. Convert the filtered array to an array of just `CDNAME`s.
3. Convert that array into a set. (This removes duplicates as sets are unordered lists of **unique** values. Adding a value that already exists in a set doesn't change the set.)
4. Convert the set back into an array.
5. Sort the array.
6. Join the array, using `<br>` as the separator.

---

Working example:

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    const myObjjj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

    const cdNames = myObjjj.features.filter(
      c => c.properties.AREAID === 'area4'
    ).map(
      res => res.properties.CDNAME
    );
    const results = Array.from(new Set(cdNames)).sort().join('<br>');

    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = results;
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://api.npoint.io/eed1932ca3c208946d86", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Read data from External JSON file using JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>
        Data extracted from External JSON file using JavaScript.
    </h3>
        <p id="list" style="border: 2px solid yellow;"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm really bad at JavaScript. I'm trying to replace "original code" with your code and its not working for me. Can you please edit your answer so that I am able to run the code snippet?

Comment: @Discover Normally we expect you to put some effort into it. If others write your code for you, you don't learn anything. Regardless, I've added a working example. The likely issue you ran across was that you named the relevant variable `result` while I named it `results`.